# OneToMany relation using thymeleaf? how to get list of object from a form using thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, thymeleaf, server-side-rendering

these are my entities:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class InvoiceInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long primaryKey;
   
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoiceInfo",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Product> listOfProducts=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long productId;
    private String productName;
   
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_info_primary_key")
    private InvoiceInfo invoiceInfo;
```

How should i get a listofproduct as i mentioned in my invoice entity as an input from a thymeleaf form?

Comment: Make it clear what do you want ? do you want display List<Product> from InvoiceInfo ?

Comment: no @Eyasu . I want to take list as an input from the form. Right now I am using name="addressList[0].city"........ like this.I am using name parameter but is there any other way using thymeleaf to do the same?

Comment: If I get you, check the modified answer, I made it on may past project. It get list of beneficiary id which is selected by check box and user id.

Answer (score 0):

Request DTO

```
public class ClaimsRequestDto {
    private int id; //come from controller or user id 
    private List<Integer> beneficiariesList; // I get Id of selected beneficeries from beneficieriesList // 
}
```

Controller

```
model.addAttribute("beneficiariesList", beneficiariesResponseDtoList);
model.addAttribute("id", user.getId());
model.addAttribute("claimsRequestDto ", new ClaimsRequestDto ());
```

Form

```
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/path}" th:object="${claimsRequestDto}">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" th:value="${id}"/>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-8">    
            <ul>
                <th:block th:each="beneficieriesIndex : ${beneficieriesList}">
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox"
                               th:name="beneficiariesList"
                               th:value="${beneficieriesIndex.id}"/>
                        <label th:text="${beneficieriesIndex.firstName+' '+beneficieriesIndex.middleName+' '+beneficieriesIndex.lastName}"></label>
                    </li>
                </th:block>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Request</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I try to send list of Id but you can try it by entity rather than id

```
<th:value="${beneficieriesIndex.id}"/> to <th:value="${beneficieriesIndex}"/>

<th:name="beneficiariesList"> => on rquest dto
```